# React-Redux - how to handle nested property implementation for payloads and reducers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

The implementation for nested payload objects and reducers is kinda confusing for me - as i cannot see how it should be implemented.

Imagine having some user input in UI that outputs a **json** like this:

```
{
 obj1: 'object 1',
 obj2: 'object 2',
 obj3: [{
    nestedObj1: 'nested object 1',
    nestedObj2: 'nested object 1',
    nestedObj3: [{
                deepNestedObj1: 'deep nested obj 1',
                deepNestedObj2: 'deep nested obj 2',
       }],
}
```

.. and you then have to implement an action creator first og foremost. This is what i **imagined** an action creator would look like:

```
export function addItem(obj1, obj2, obj3) {
return {
type:ADD_ITEM,
payload: {
  obj1,
  obj2,
  obj3: [{
    nestedObj1,
    nestedObj2,
    nestedObj3: [{
      deepNestedObj1,
      deepNestedObj2,
    }]
  }]
}}
}
```

**Now my question is:** is how the action creator meant to be used when working with deep nested json objects?

Comment: structure of payload depends upon you totally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would strongly recommend **against** writing an action creator that way.  Per our Redux Style Guide docs page, you should:

- [Put as much logic as possible into reducers](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#put-as-much-logic-as-possible-in-reducers)
- [Let reducers own the state shape](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#reducers-should-own-the-state-shape)
- [Model actions as "events", not "setters"](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#model-actions-as-events-not-setters)

Also, you should really be using [our official Redux Toolkit package](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux), which will greatly simplify your Redux logic.

I would recommend writing this along the lines of:

```js
const itemsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "items",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    itemAdded(state, action) {
      const {id1, id2, value} = action.payload;
      if (state[id1]) {
        state[id1][id2].push(value);
      }
    }

  }
})
```

So, keep the actions as minimal as possible - they should have enough info to describe what happened, and let the reducer figure out how the state should be updated in response.

Comment: From what i understood from the docs: the "createSlice" is a combination of "createAction" and "createReducer" - so that basically means i can get rid of my action.js and actionTypes.js which stores all my actions and actionType constants in exchange for a single file containing "createSlide" that handles all logic in one place. Correct me if im wrong please.

Comment: Pretty much, yes!  See https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#structure-files-as-feature-folders-with-single-file-logic and https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-2-app-structure for examples.

Comment: the "Model Actions as Events, Not Setters" section in the style guidelines is somehow describing what i should avoid and do instead. 

I thought actions should know the exact payloads - in other words: every nested payload there is. But the docs says the opposite of what i was thinking, no?

Comment: Correct. An action should contain the minimal amount of data needed to describe what happened, _not_ the complete recalculated resulting state. Let the reducer decide what the final state needs to be and do the work of processing it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If cheap solution is what you are looking for you can always copy your properties into a new object. Just copy any state into an object before you overwrite properties of said object with user input, at that point call the reducer with new object.

Comment: Im looking for permanent solution that can handle complex json data